# Importing a .txt file with nested array into powershell

Tags: powershell

Info edit: I'm wanting to build a .txt file that contains a nested array like the below format, where I can pull the name of the VM and what days I want it to backup. I have a manual backup script working, but I want to pull the VM name variables from the array into the script IF it's the day it's supposed to run. The backup script is run through powershell as a scheduled task.

I have a .txt file containing info in the format: `[[VM1],[Monday, Thursday]]`.

I want to import this into powershell and reference array values in the format: $file[1], $file[2], etc... inside of a for loop at each line. Is this possible in powershell. I also try this with import-csv, but it's running without an error but outputting nothing.

```
$Sched = import-csv -path ".\Schedule.txt"
$VMNames = ""
Write-Host $Sched
foreach ($i in $Sched)

{

    $VMNames = $i[0]
    Write-Host $VMNames
}
```

I would like $i[0] to output VM1 in this example.

Comment: please, post your code ... i have _no freaking idea_ what you are wanting. [*blush*]

Comment: I updated with my unit test. i want $i[1] to output VM1

Comment: thanks ... now i have some idea what is going on. [*grin*] however, you will likely need to post both _several_ lines of the input AND those same lines in the output. right now it looks like `$i[1]` would be `Monday, Thursday` ... but that makes very little sense.

Comment: My problem is that when i submit this. JUST This, with the aforementioned data in the file. There is no output at all. It runs and that's it.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Please take a step back, edit the question and explain with more details what this is about. Where do you get the strange input format anyway? It looks like some kind of container.

Comment: `[[VM1],[Monday, Thursday]]` What format is this?  It's certainly not CSV.  It's not JSON, either.  It doesn't appear to be a standard format for anything.  My guess is that you'll have to parse it with a regular expression.

Comment: I've added some info on the background leading to this. I hope it clarifies it a bit. I am pretty new to powershell so I may being going down the rabbit-hole trying to complete it like i would in python.

Comment: @BaconBits That is the array format for python. It's all just saved in .txt. I tried get-content, but $i[0] pulls the first '[' instead of VM1 since it considers it a string.

Comment: PLEASE post several examples - either several files if they are in one-per-file OR several lines if they are several-per-file. THEN please post what you want to do with that data --- note, that is not "access like an array". it's "what is the goal". ///// it looks like what you want is to parse an python representation of an array into a powershell array so that you can use it in PoSh. from what i can see you likely want a hashtable for looking up "the systems that need to be worked on today".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[edit - i posted the wrong version. thanks to Jonathon Crowder for pointing out the 2nd day was not getting added to the lookup table.]*

this seems to do what i *think* you actually want ... get the VM names for those that should be dealt with on a specified day.

i *think* that is what you want. [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
[[VM1],[Monday, Thursday]]
[[VM2],[Sunday]]
[[VM3],[Wednesday, Saturday]]
[[VM5],[Monday, Thursday]]
[[VM6],[Tuesday, Friday]]
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$DayNames = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.DayNames
$DailyLookup = @{}
foreach ($DN_Item in $DayNames)
    {
    $DailyLookup.Add($DN_Item, '')
    }

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    # forgot to trim out the leftover space on the 2nd day name
    #$SplitIS_Item = $IS_Item.Split(',').Trim('[]')
    $SplitIS_Item = $IS_Item.Split(',').Trim('[]').Trim()
    $VMName = $SplitIS_Item[0]
    # forgot to include all the _remaining_ items
    #    this left out the 2nd day name
    #$TriggerDays = $SplitIS_Item[1]
    $TriggerDays = $SplitIS_Item.Where({$_ -ne $VMName})

    foreach ($TD_Item in $TriggerDays)
        {
        $DailyLookup[$TD_Item] = (($DailyLookup[$TD_Item], $VMName) -join ', ').Trim(', ')
        }
    }

$DailyLookup['Monday']
```

output ...

```
VM1, VM5
```

that output is a *string*, not an array. so you will need to split & trim it to get the individual VM items. the original had an array there, but i was unsure how you wanted to use the data.

Comment: Ok, this would definitely work with the goal of it. I can use the string output as is to send to my script. However, this only parses the first result in the second entry in the array. For entries like Thursday and Friday, that are listed second, they are not collected. I get some of the script, but don't understand enough of what you wrote to see if I can correct that.

Comment: you didn't provide any such item in your sample data. [*grin*] ///// the `$SplitIS_Item` line splits the line into parts and then trims away any leading/trailing `[]` chars. you will need to experiment with that line to get what you need ... OR you could provide the REPEATEDLY requested "several samples" so that one could work with a realistic data set. [*frown*] ///// i fail to understand your refusal to do that ...

Comment: Your "sample input" is the same as what i'm working with. The example i have in my original post is all I have right now. There are no other samples as i'm building the reference file as Im testing. I felt that i had communicated that. So it's been frustrating on my end being asked for things I don't have. So I would treat: 

    [[VM1],[Monday, Thursday]]
    [[VM2],[Sunday]]
    [[VM3],[Wednesday, Saturday]]
    [[VM5],[Monday, Thursday]] 
    [[VM6],[Tuesday, Friday]]   

as the sample data set. (i.e. the one you created in your example. I'm sorry for any confusion though.

Comment: so ............ um, er, what on earth were you talking about when you said `For entries like Thursday and Friday, that are listed second, they are not collected`? i do NOT understand. what does `listed 2nd` mean? [*frown*]

Comment: when you replace $DailyLookup['Monday'] with $DailyLookup['Friday'] the output is Null. Your example isn't reading the second day in the list. That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: aha! i finally figured out what you mean ... sorry for being so dense. i posted the wrong version of my code. i'll go back and fix that. as you said, it only included the _first_ day in the list. [*blush*]

Comment: i wish my votes counted yet. Thank you so much for your help. After looking through it much more I can see what each step does, but you took a much different approach that helped me. Sorry for the delays!

Comment: @JonathonCrowder - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]